# executing a forloop in a particular time

Tags: java, android

This is my `onDraw` method, which I use to create my sprites and draw them every fps =10:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(21, 181, 195));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);

    for (Sprite wave1 : sprites) {
        wave1.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

i want to run this for loop in this code again and again ... i tried to run it with timer task but when i write this for loop inside my timer task method it say error it says i can be used only in a canvas class  and also showing error on receiving the image from resource files  even after trying to get resource file there it says error again saying it can be used only inside a sprite class :(
so i want a way to run this  for loop here in timed interval in this same Ondraw method 
 : Any ideas how to do it ? try ed handler class too :

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Thread?
Maybe this could help you: http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/